# Make a numpy array of sets from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, set

I am trying to make a list of groups that I extract from a list of lists.
The main list I have contains lists which are of different lengths. I want to group up all the sub-lists that contain at least one value from another sub-list efficiently.
For instance I want this:

```
[[2],[5],[5,8,16],[7,9,12],[9,20]]
```

to be grouped up like this

```
my_groups = {"group1":[2], "group2":[5,8,16], "group3":[7,9,12,20]}
```

The way I thought of doing this is to create convert the sub-lists into sets and using reduce intersect1d

```
reduce(np.intersect1d, (SUPERLIST))
```

and then put the results in a dictionary. But I don't know how to convert it to an array of sets without iterating through the list.
Is there a way to do this or a more efficient way that I am missing?

### **Edit**

Without numpy I would do something like this:

```
my_dict = dict()
unique_id = 0
for sub_list_ref in super_list:
    sub_set_ref = set(sub_list_ref)
    for sub_list_comp in super_list:
        sub_set_comp = set(sub_list_comp)
        if len(sub_set_ref.intersection(sub_set_comp))>0:
            my_dict[unique_id] = sub_set_ref.union(sub_set_comp)
            updated_id = unique_id+1
    if updated_id == unique_id:
        my_dict[unique_id] = sub_list_ref
    else:
        unique_id = updated_id
```

### **Edit 2**

Yesterday this question got an excellent answer from DarryIG and today I managed to make a more efficient version.

```
def coalesce_groups(current_list, super_list, iterations):
    if iterations <= 0:
        print("YOU HAVE ITERATED MORE THAN 3 TIMES")

    tmp_list = current_list
    for element in current_list:
        tmp_list = tmp_list + super_list[element]
    # Take only the unique elements
    tmp_list = list(set(tmp_list))

    if tmp_list == list(set(current_list)):
        return tmp_list
    else:
        iterations-=1
        return coalesce_groups(tmp_list, super_list, iterations)

def dict_of_groups(original_list):
    lst = list(original_list).copy()
    result_list = []

    for it in lst:
        result = coalesce_groups(it, lst, iterations = 3)
        if len(result)!=0:
            result_list.append(result)
        for t in result:
            lst[t] = []
    result_dict = { x : result_list[x] for x in range(0, len(result_list) ) }
    return result_dict
```

In test (on jupyter notebook)

```
lst = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [16, 6], [8, 10, 18, 21, 27, 7], [10, 19, 21, 27, 40, 8], [13, 20, 22, 26, 28, 30, 34, 41, 42, 50, 9], [18, 21, 27, 10], [11], [12], [20, 22, 26, 28, 30, 34, 41, 42, 50, 13], [14], [15], [16], [25, 17], [21, 27, 40, 18], [21, 27, 40, 19], [22, 26, 28, 30, 34, 41, 42, 50, 20], [27, 40, 21], [26, 28, 30, 34, 41, 42, 50, 22], [23], [24], [25], [28, 30, 34, 41, 42, 50, 26], [40, 27], [30, 34, 41, 42, 50, 28], [29], [34, 41, 42, 50, 30], [33, 31], [32], [33], [41, 42, 50, 34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [42, 50, 41], [50, 42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [49, 48], [49], [50]]
%lprun -T lprof0 -f generate_groups generate_groups(lst)
print(open('lprof0', 'r').read())
%lprun -T lprof1 -f dict_of_groups dict_of_groups(lst)
print(open('lprof1', 'r').read())
```

Additional answers will be taken into consideration but I believe his is still valid and the more complete for this question.

DarryIG is still king

Comment: Lists cannot be n-dimensional.  numpy arrays can, but you don't show any.  But given your example, this looks like Python dictionary, set, and list problem.  Trying to use numpy will only complicate things.  So for a start, show us what you'd do without numpy.

Comment: edited the question to address your comment. I am aware that there are edge cases in what I wrote but more or less it gives the idea

Comment: python aet operations are based on hashing, like its dicts.  numpy set like operations use sorting.

Comment: Your example code "using numpy" produces an incorrect result, namely: {0: {2}, 1: {8, 16, 5}, 2: {16, 5, 8}, 3: {20, 7, 9, 12}, 4: {9, 20}}.  It has too many sublists in the output.

Comment: Why would you want to put `set` objects inside `numpy.ndarray` objects? That makes very little sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done efficienly using Union-Find algorithm from graphs (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find-algorithm-set-2-union-by-rank/)

We consider each sublist as a vertex in a graph.

Two vertexes are connected if their sublists overlap (i.e. intersect).

Union-find provides an efficient method of finding all disjoint subsets of non-overlapping vertices.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

# a structure to represent a graph 
class Graph: 

    def __init__(self, num_of_v): 
        self.num_of_v = num_of_v 
        self.edges = defaultdict(list) 

    # graph is represented as an  
    # array of edges 
    def add_edge(self, u, v): 
        self.edges[u].append(v) 


class Subset: 
    def __init__(self, parent, rank): 
        self.parent = parent 
        self.rank = rank 

    def __repr__(self):
        return {'name':self.parent, 'age':self.rank}

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Subset(parent='+str(self.parent)+', rank='+str(self.rank)+ ')'

# A utility function to find set of an element 
# node(uses path compression technique) 
def find(subsets, node): 
    if subsets[node].parent != node: 
        subsets[node].parent = find(subsets, subsets[node].parent) 
    return subsets[node].parent 

# A function that does union of two sets  
# of u and v(uses union by rank) 
def union(subsets, u, v): 

    # Attach smaller rank tree under root  
    # of high rank tree(Union by Rank) 
    if subsets[u].rank > subsets[v].rank: 
        subsets[v].parent = u 
    elif subsets[v].rank > subsets[u].rank: 
        subsets[u].parent = v 

    # If ranks are same, then make one as  
    # root and increment its rank by one 
    else: 
        subsets[v].parent = u 
        subsets[u].rank += 1

def find_disjoint_sets(graph): 

    # Allocate memory for creating sets 
    subsets = [] 

    for u in range(graph.num_of_v): 
        subsets.append(Subset(u, 0)) 

    # Iterate through all edges of graph,  
    # find sets of both vertices of every  
    # edge, if sets are same, then there 
    # is cycle in graph. 
    for u in graph.edges: 
        u_rep = find(subsets, u) 

        for v in graph.edges[u]: 
            v_rep = find(subsets, v) 

            if u_rep == v_rep: 
                continue
            else: 
                union(subsets, u_rep, v_rep) 

    return subsets

def generate_groups(lst):
  """ Finds disjoint sublists in lst.  Performs a union of sublists that intersect """
  # Generate graph
  g = Graph(len(lst))

  # Loop over all pairs of subists, 
  # Place an edge in the graph for sublists that intersect
  for i1, v1 in enumerate(lst):
    set_v1 = set(v1)
    for i2, v2 in enumerate(lst):
      if i2 > i1 and set_v1.intersection(v2):
        g.add_edge(i1, i2)

  # Disjoint subsets of sublists
  subsets = find_disjoint_sets(g)

  # Union of sublists which are non-disjoint (i.e. have the same parent)
  d = {}
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    sublist_index = find(subsets, i)
    if not sublist_index in d:
      d[sublist_index] = set()

    d[sublist_index] = d[sublist_index].union(lst[i])

  return d

# Test Code
lst = [[2],[5],[5,8,16],[7,9,12],[9,20]]

d = generate_groups(lst)
print(d)
```

**Output**

{0: {2}, 1: {8, 16, 5}, 3: {9, 12, 20, 7}}

Comment: Thank you very much DarryIG. Unless someone is able to answer the question with numpy I will flag it as the right answer.

Comment: @JorgeDiaz--I'm looking to see if I can improve the performance of the for loops that are slow in Python.  I will get back on this.